# Determine $E[X]$, $E[X^2]$ and $Var[X]$ from probabilites.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, variance

**Task**:
A basketball player shoots two freethrows. The probability for hitting the first short is $0.8$. If he makes the first short, he becomes confident and hits the second one with probability $0.9$. If he in turn misses the first shot, he becomes insecure and only hits the second shot with probability $0.5$. Let $X$ denote the number of successful shots.

I need to determine $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$.

What I have done so far was to calculate all probabilities for $P(X=0), P(X=1), P(X=2)$ using a tree.

Can you give me an ansatz on calculating $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$?

Comment: Just do it by hand, what's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "do it by hand"?

Comment: Just compute those quantities using the standard definitions in the standard way.   There is no difficulty at all. Do you know the definition of, say, $E[X]$?

Comment: It is defined like this: $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$. But what is x and f(x) in this case?

Comment: Well, for a continuous distribution, sure.  What does that formula mean in the discrete case?

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20the%20expected,outcomes%20of%20a%20random%20variable.) is a basic discussion on Expected Value.  The discrete case is, of course, treated first.

Comment: Oh, I see. But how can you determine $E[X^2]$ then? Just square $E[X] = x_1*p_1, ..., x_n*p_n$ like $E[X] = x_1^2*p_1, ..., x_n^2*p_n$?

Comment: Please learn the basic definitions, that's the source of your confusion here.  In this case, for any function $f$, $E[F(X)]=\sum_{i=0}^2 F(i)P(X=i)$.  The definitions matter and you can learn them in your reference materials or in the link I provided.